# Laravel 5.5 (Auth) - Remember Me on multiple devices

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel's auth providers can only remember one browser correctly, since it stores `remember_token` in the `users` table.

I would like to enable the possibility of keeping multiple devices logged in on a same user account, with a way to manually abort any device access, as a lot of popular services allow us to do so (ex: Google, Facebook, iCloud and their `Connected devices` page from which we can disconnect a phone or a computer).

My app actually uses the `database` driver for storing sessions. In order to try to modify the way it keeps users logged in, I registered a `CustomUserProvider` that simply extends `EloquentUserProvider` at the moment, so I could easily overwrite the following methods:

```
public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token);
public function updateRememberToken(UserContract $user, $token);
```

I am a little lost at this point, does anyone have already implemented a similar auth cycle, or have any advice that could help me implementing this without creating any security vulnerability?

Comment: Just add a related table to the remember tokens so the user can have many then query that table in retriveByToken and return the related user

Comment: @MikeMiller In that case, how could I know which row of this table I should update when `updateRememberToken` is called ?

Comment: I suppose you would need to keep some kind of ID for the device the token relates to

Comment: Or maybe `remember_token` is never updated ? And `updateRememberToken ` is only called when we log in with "Remember me" checked ? So it would only add a row, each time, to this table...

Comment: Yeah you could do that. Probably would require some rule for discarding tokens that haven't been used in some amount of time